# Domain Admin's Android refusing to activesync with Exchange 2013

Tags: android, activesync

I have tried for weeks to get my Galaxy S5 to connect to my exchange 2013 server. 
It appears that the exchange accepts the credentials, as there are no errors displayed, but no messages are ever sync'd. it just spins endlessly.

The following post makes me question if this is because I am a domain admin.

[How to make Android to connect nicely with Exchange Server 2013](https://serverfault.com/questions/499080/how-to-make-android-to-connect-nicely-with-exchange-server-2013?rq=1)

So IF I read this post correctly, this is telling me that I cannot use my android with my domain email account without compromising the domain security?

Any thoughts about this?

note that there are plenty of other users here who use Iphones, and a couple other androids that work fine.

Comment: Why are you using an account with DA to read email?  You are begging for a malware/phishing attack.

Comment: ^^^ Agreed. There's no valid reason for doing this.

Comment: I spend 90+% of my day doing administrator stuff. 

Does the rest of the administrative world really keep 2 accounts to function?

Seriously? I'd spend half my day switching between accounts just to do my job.

And to answer Jim B, I currently never use my email unless connected to the LAN or VPN. but that sometimes makes my response time really slow.

So are you telling me that the other admins using iphones with no problems are begging for attacks? 

Even if we use SSL?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The formatting didn't work on that post, and makes it seem rather aggressive. That's not how it was intended.

Comment: `I spend 90+% of my day doing administrator stuff. Does the rest of the administrative world really keep 2 accounts to function?` - Yes, they do. See this question and the accepted answer. - http://serverfault.com/questions/575050/is-it-best-practices-to-have-separate-login-for-a-domain-for-domain-admins

Answer (score 0):

it's an old post yes but no actual reply to the OP's question.

to the OP, if you're using the Android mail client sometimes that is the issue. use some other mail client like BlueMail from the app store.

hth anyone in the same situation.